# How to change the password hashing scheme in LDAP using an external library with slapd.d config

Tags: passwords, hash, password-management, ldap

I am trying to change the password hashing scheme for LDAP. Hypothetically, let's assume it's `pw-argon.so`

I don't have `slapd.conf` I have the `slapd.d` directory where I can make changes dynamically to the daemon.

- What changes do I have to make in the `cn=` config DIT so that I can put that hashing algorithm into action without restarting slapd?

Here are the steps that I tried out:

I tried to update the `cn=module{0}`

```
dn: cn=module{0},cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcModuleLoad
olcModuleLoad: pw-argon.so
```

upon running an LDAP modify request for this, I got the following output:

```
ldap_initialize( ldapi:///??base )
add olcModuleLoad:
    pw-argon.so
modifying entry "cn=module{0},cn=config"
ldap_modify: Naming violation (64)
    additional info: naming attribute 'cn' is not present in entry
```

I know I have to update the `olcDatabase={-1}frontend` as well. But I do not know if I am doing things right. Can someone guide me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying modify an **existing** entry. The error message you provided indicates that you tried to add a **new** entry. You should use CLI tool `ldapmodify` (instead of `ldapadd`).